# Menu AdminLTE de acordo com o usuário

Tags: laravel, menu, adminlte

Estou criando um sistema de agendamento com o Laravel e AdminLTE. O método de autenticação que utilizei não foi o Auth do Laravel nem do AdminLTE, pois usei simplesmente um Controller que usa um método para autenticação no meu AD (ldap_connect e ldap_bind). Realizado o login, o próprio controller vai pesquisar na minha tabela users (utilizando o cpf obtido do AD) o campo level que contém 1 ou 2 (1 para admin e 2 para usuários). A intenção é que o menu do AdminLTE seja diferente para o admin e para os usuários. Tentei editar o arquivo AppServiceProvider, porém ele não recupera a session com o get(), então não consigo criar meu menu. Sei que utilizando o método de autenticação tradicional do Laravel isso funcionaria bem, porém no meu caso é diferente.

```
Trecho da autenticação LoginController.php
```

$user = DB::table('users')
          ->where('cpf', '=', $usr)
          ->first();

```
      if (isset($user)) {
        if ($user->level == '1') {
          Session::put('admin', $user->level);
        } else {
          Session::put('admin', '2');
        }
      }else {
        Session::put('admin', '2');
      }

      $level = Session::get('admin');

      return view('welcome', compact('cpf', 'email', 'tel', 'nome', 'level'));
```

Tentei utilizar o Laratrust

**App\MyMenuFilter.php**

namespace App;

use JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\Menu\Builder;
use JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\Menu\Filters\FilterInterface;
use Laratrust;

class MyMenuFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    public function transform($item, Builder $builder)
    {
        if (isset($item['permission']) && ! Laratrust::can($item['permission'])) {
            return false;
        }

```
    return $item;
}
```

}

**config\adminlte.php**

'menu' => [
        'AGENDA',
        [
            'text'    => 'Configurações',
            'icon'    => 'calendar',
            'permission'  => 'configuracoes', //aqui o usuário não vê
            'submenu' => [
                [
                    'text' => 'Mensal',
                    'url'  => '#',
                    'icon_color' => 'red',
                    'submenu' => [
                        [
                            'text' => 'Disponibilizar',
                            'url'  => '#',
                            'icon' => 'calendar-plus-o',
                        ],
                        [
                            'text'    => 'Excluir',
                            'url'     => '#',
                            'icon' => 'calendar-minus-o '

`],
                    [
                        'text' => 'Ver',
                        'url'  => '#',
                        'icon' => 'calendar-check-o',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'text' => 'Diário',
                'url'  => '#',
                'icon_color' => 'yellow',
                'submenu' => [
                    [
                        'text' => 'Disponibilizar',
                        'url'  => '#',
                        'icon' => 'calendar-plus-o',
                    ],
                    [
                        'text'    => 'Excluir',
                        'url'     => '#',
                        'icon' => 'calendar-minus-o '

                    ],
                    [
                        'text' => 'Ver',
                        'url'  => '#',
                        'icon' => 'calendar-check-o',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'CONFIGURAÇÕES DE USUÁRIO',
    [
        'text' => 'Administradores',
        'url'  => 'admin/settings',
        'icon' => 'user-secret',
        'submenu' => [
            [
                'text' => 'Criar',
                'url'  => '#',
                'icon' => 'user-plus',
            ],
            [
                'text'    => 'Ver',
                'url'     => '#',
                'icon' => 'users'

            ],
          ],
    ],
    'AVISOS',
    [
        'text'       => 'Agendamentos de hoje',
        'icon_color' => 'red',
        'label' => 2,
        'label_color' => 'success',
    ],
    [
        'text'       => 'Eventos de hoje',
        'icon_color' => 'yellow',
        'label'      =>  4,
    ],
    [
        'text'       => 'Total de Agendamentos',
        'icon_color' => 'aqua',
        'label'      => 2,
    ],
],`